# How to change datetime to INT in snowflake?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have a table that contains a datetime column in datetime format, see picture for example.

[image]

I need to convert this timestamp to YYYYMMDD in int, something like this:

[image]

I'm trying this query, but it does not work.

```
select Cast(Cast(Cast (DATETIME AS DATE Format 'YYYYMMDD') AS VARCHAR(8))AS INT) AS DATE_KEY
  FROM TBL_A
```

Comment: *doesn't work* provides exactly no information about actual issue. You even cannot say if this code syntactically incorrect or the data fails some operation without "compilation in the mind". Please, always post an error code and message **in text format** or clearly describe *what* exactly doesn't work and *how*.

Answer (score 8):

- `to_char` converts a date using a format
- `::int` casts to int

```sql
with data as (
    select current_timestamp() datetime
)


select to_char(datetime, 'YYYYMMDD')::int
from data
```

(with that said, I wouldn't recommend this type of int representation for a date)

Comment: with dimensional modeling it is a best practice to store a date this way.